# Is my work still halal after migrating from pirated windows to linux ubuntu?

Tags: halal-haram, software, piracy

so i have a pirated windows 7 and want to move to linux ubuntu using my windows 7 to download and burn linux ubuntu file into a disc, if i work using that ubuntu OS that i get using pirated windows, is my earnings halal or haram?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. I'd say the correct formulation of your question title is: Is my income halal!

Answer (score -2):

assalam alikom brother you must ask a sheikh which have a good knowledge in Islam that can answer you with the evidences of hadith or qurran . but at all i think you are in the wrong way from the beginning of using a pirated sowfware.